# AWS ECS run latest task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to have run the lastest task definition image built from GitHub deployment (CD). Seems like on AWS it creates a task definition for example "**task-api:1**", "**task-api:2**", on was my cluster is still running **task-api: 1** even though there is the latest task as a new image has been built. So far I have to manually stop the old one and start a new one . How can I have it automated?

Comment: How did you create task definition and ECS Service? Did you create them manually or used CloudFormation or CDK?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I created my task via the AWS console, I am running just the task definition on its own without service plus service with task definition launched via the EC2 not target both of them, so in the task definition JSON file on my Github both repositories they are tied to a revision of a task (could that be a problem?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap your tasks in a service and use **rolling updates** for automated deployments.

When the rolling update (ECS) deployment type is used for your service, when a new service deployment is started the Amazon ECS service scheduler replaces the currently running tasks with new tasks.

Read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-type-ecs.html

This is DevOps, so you need a CI/CD pipeline that will do the rolling updates for you. Look at CodeBuild, CodeDeploy and CodePipeline (and CodeCommit if you integrate your code repository in AWS with your CI/CD)

Read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy.html

This is a complex topic, but it pays off in the end.

Comment: yes I have been using this option (rolling updates), but I don't have CI/CD set up via GitHub not via AWS code deploy feature (i could be missing the fact that you're saying I dump Github CI/CD to use AWS deploy please clarify that part ), but the newly pushed image in Repository fails to use the latest code changes in the latest image, I am having to manually update the service with a new task that for reason has the sam configs but seems like when loaded it will load with the new code changes from the latest image. I have been using the same image URL by the way.

Comment: When I update the service I have to deregister old revisions of the task definition .so I end up doing it manually after I had thought this could be done automatically or there is a config that can resolve all of this? That's the burning part of the question for me.

Comment: If you are able to push from your CI/CD to ECR that is enough.

Comment: Your DevOps journey for ECS rolling updates does not stop there. You have to implement an External Deployment as explained here (because you are not using the AWS native CodePipeline): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-type-external.html

Answer (score 1):

Judging from what you have said in the comments:

> I created my task via the AWS console, I am running just the task definition on its own without service plus service with task definition launched via the EC2 not target both of them, so in the task definition JSON file on my Github both repositories they are tied to a revision of a task (could that be a problem?).

It's difficult to understand exactly how you have this set up and it'd probably be a good idea for you to go back and understand the services you are using a little better using the guide you are following or AWS documentation. Pushing a new task definition does not automatically update services to use the new definition.

That said, my guess is that you need to update the service in ECS to use the latest task definition. You can do that in many ways:

- Through the console (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-service-console-v2.html).
- Through the CLI (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html).
- Through the IaC like the CDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecs-readme.html).

This can be automated but you would need to set up a process to automate it.

I would recommend reading some guides on how you could automate deployment and updates using the CDK. Amazon provide a good guide to get you started https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/ecs_example.html.